# Save multiple values ​in a single formControl [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form. In the typescript I have an array of quantity materials that are added or removed from an inventory. Which is displayed in the html by an ngFor.
What I am looking for is that in the FormControl, I can add several values ​​depending on the materials.
That is, if I have X materials, something like `[material 1, material 2, material 3]` appears in the same formControl. Since I don't know how many materials are added.
Same for the code of the new material and the old material. I don't know if I'm making myself understood. But this is my code.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let material of materials">
  <mat-form-field class="col-md-4">
    <mat-select required placeholder="Select Material" formControlName="materials">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let object of objects" [value]="object">
        {{ object }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="col-md-4">
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="new" />
    <mat-label>Code New Material</mat-label>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="col-md-4">
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="old" />
    <mat-label>Code Old Material</mat-label>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
    <button
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
      class="btn bnt-primary btn-block"
      (click)="addMaterial()"
    >
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      <span> Add Material</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <button
      mat-raised-button
      color="warn"
      class="btn bnt-primary btn-block"
      (click)="removeMaterial()"
    >
      <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
      <span> Remove Material</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my typescript

```
    export class MaterialComponent implements OnInit {
      materials: number[] = [1];
      objects: string[] = ['MATERIAL 1', 'MATERIAL 2','MATERIAL 3', 'MATERIAL 4'];
      form: FormGroup;
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,){
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.makeForm();
      }
      makeForm() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          materials: [''],
          new: [''],
          old: [''],
        });
    } 
   addMaterial(){
    this.materiales.push(1);
  }
  removeMaterial(){
    this.materiales.pop();
  }
    }
```

If I do `console.log(this.form.get('materials').value)` It only gets the first value. I would like to take all the values for each Input of the ngFor

Comment: Not clear what you exactly want to do

Comment: Do you mean multiple values in the same input separated with comma?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: You could use Angular Material Chips https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question user will add or remove materials using a button then you want to update a form control according to the elements in the array on that specific time.This can be achieved by using patch functionality to form control after push or pop operation.

```
   addMaterial(){
    this.materiales.push(1);
     //Update what ever the formcontrol you want here as per requirement
     this.form.patchValue({
      materials: function (){
        let temp = "",
        this.materials.forEach(index,value){
           temp += value;
         }
        return temp;
      }
    });
    
  }
  removeMaterial(){
    this.materiales.pop();
    //Update what ever the formcontrol you want here as per requirement
    this.form.patchValue({
      materials: this.materials
    });
  }
```

[Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)